# How to javascript round down number - continue

Tags: javascript, rounding

This is a bit different from my question before

[How to round up using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191088/how-to-javascript-round-up-number)

I have this set of number and want to round down to 1 decimal point. Since standard javascript round up function cant meet my requirement, hope someone can help me :)

Below is the ouput needed when round down:

192.168 => **192.10**
192.11 => **192.10**
192.21 =>**192.20**
192.26 => **192.20**
192.30 = > **192.30**

Comment: looks like you want to round *down* to *1* decimal point.

Comment: sorry for the misleading question. i edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not rounding, 
192.168 rounded to two decimal places is 192.20.

However for your requirement :
You might just want to multiply it by multiples of 10, take 'floor' , and then divide by same number.

see it here : http://jsfiddle.net/7qeGH/

```
var numbers = new Array(192.168,192.11 ,192.21 ,192.26 ,192.30 );

var response = "";

for(var i =0 ; i< numbers.length ; i++)

{
     var rounded = Math.floor(numbers[i]*10)/10  + '0';  // '0' is added as string
     response +=   numbers[i] + " => " + rounded + "\n";

}

alert(response);
```

Comment: hi i cant understand your sentence of take 'floor'

Answer (score 1):

How about `Math.round(number * 10) / 10` ? You'll get a result with 1 decimal so you can add a zero at the end `(Math.round(number * 10) / 10) + "0"`

But actually you round down not up. So it would be `Math.floor()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this :

```
var mynum = 192.168;
var result=Math.round(mynum*100)/100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple

```
testVal = Math.round(YourNumberHere*100)/100 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you simply trying to floor? That is, "round **down**".

```
Math.floor(the_number*10)/ 10)
```