# how to round up the numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to round up a number to 2 decimal places, such as 312.12.

Here is my code which doesn't work correctly. Could you please suggest what I am doing wrong.

```
(document.getElementById("AmtReturn").value = valAmtRefund*valConvRate;) 
   function populateAmtReturned(){
        var valConvRate = document.getElementById("convRate").value;
        var valAmtRefund = document.getElementById("AmtRefund").value;
        var valAmtReturn = document.getElementById("AmtReturn").value;
    if(!(valAmtRefund.length >0))
        {
            ShowErrorEx('AmtRefund','Amount Refunded');
            return false;
        }
    if(valConvRate.length > 0 )
    {
        if (ValidateConvsionEx('convRate',true,'conversion rate'))
        {
            document.getElementById("AmtReturn").value =valAmtRefund*valConvRate;           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191088/how-to-javascript-round-up-number

Answer (score 5):

Use `Math.round` for rounding. Use `Math.ceil` for rounding up. Use `Math.floor` for rounding down.

Or use `.toFixed()` if you just want to strip out the decimals:

```
var num = 12.43;
num.toFixed(); // 12
```

Note that `.toFixed()` returns a `string`, not `number`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to round to two digits and always round up do

```
var original=28.453

var result=Math.ceil(original*100)/100
```

Answer (score 1):

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

```
312.123456.toFixed(2);  // "312.12"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just have a decimal number and want to round it use `Math.round(number)`

```
Math.round(2.1) // Will return true
```