# Rounding UP to next integer with javascript even if value is 1.00000000001

Tags: javascript, math

How can I round a number entered into a text box and divided by 18, UP regardless of whether its below the .5 (with Javascript/jQuery). Currently I am using:

```
nopallets=parseInt(howmany/18);
```

But this rounds either down or up depending on which integer it is closest to.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: The answer is available on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191088/how-to-round-up-a-number-in-javascript

Comment: why on earth was my question downvoted? :/ that's just silly, the link provided does not answer my question so I haven't re-posted a question that's already been asked.

Comment: Two things. 1. I didn't downvote (so chill out, mate). 2. Ceil is the answer, here and in the linked question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Math.ceil(howmany/18)` is what you want.

[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) ceil returns the smallest integer greater than or equal to a number.

Comment: MDN Docs looks currently unavailable for me, also a line break after the link should make it formatted better, the downvote is not from me :)

Comment: i gave everyone a +1 to counteract those -1s ;)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_ceil.asp

```
nopallets=Math.ceil(howmany/18);
```

Comment: Guys, many thanks for this answer and it was correct but also.. [w3fools.com](http://www.w3fools.com)

Answer (score 2):

```
nopallets= Math.ceil(number);
```

it takes the ceiling of the number

Answer (score 2):

`Math.ceil`will do that for you.
See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_ceil.asp for reference.

```
nopallets=Math.ceil(howmany/18);
```

Comment: Guys, many thanks for this answer and it was correct but also.. [w3fools.com](http://www.w3fools.com)