# Javascript:How can I round up decimal values?

Tags: javascript

I have a value like `1724.1000000000001`,How can I round up values like such to `1724.11` in javascript?
I need a generic function.Please help...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to round up a number in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191088/how-to-round-up-a-number-in-javascript) and [Round up to 2 decimal places in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-up-to-2-decimal-places-in-javascript) and [many more](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+round+number).

Comment: So, do you want to round the numbers? So, `17.10001 --> 17.10`, or `17.10001 --> 17.11`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easy way to do this is:

```
var num = 1724.1000000000001;
num = Math.ceil(num * 100) / 100;
alert(num); //  1724.11
```

**How it works:**

Ceil will round the value up. But you want to have 2 decimal numbers. The best way to do this is to:

1. Multiply the value with 100,
2. Round it up,
3. Divide it with 100.

Now you have an up rounded value with 2 decimals. 
This is what happens:

```
1724.1000000000001 * 100 = 172410.00000000001
round-up on 172410.00000000001 = 172411
172411 / 100 = 1724.11
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the example in the questions asks for a result of `1724.11` instead of `1724.1` I would assume you don't strictly want `round`, but rather `ceil`:

```
var n = 1724.10000000001;
Math.ceil(n * 100) / 100; // >> 1724.11
```

If a simple round up to the second decimal is required us `Math.round` instead of `Math.ceil`.

Comment: Look at the question - it asks the number become `1724.11` not `1724.1`, despite saying round - so I assume the OP actually wants `ceil`.

Comment: The question asks how to round UP, therefore ceil is correct

Comment: @EmilIvanov And your formula gives `1724.1` and not `1724.11`...

Comment: @Samuel Caillerie: No it does not. This is the only correct answer yet downvoted twice.

Comment: @Samuel: Who are you addressing? Emil's code is correct.

Comment: @pimvdb @Felix Kling : `Math.ceil(1724.10000000001 * 100)` gives `127410`, thus... (just tried in my firefox console)

Comment: @Samuel Caillerie: My apologies, it works in Chrome. Maybe the decimal part is too small for Firefox.

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie I would assume it overflows in FF.

Comment: @EmilIvanov:Guys I actually want to round up the value.I just showed the example.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/round.shtml:

```
var original=28.453

1) //round "original" to two decimals
var result=Math.round(original*100)/100  //returns 28.45

2) // round "original" to 1 decimal
var result=Math.round(original*10)/10  //returns 28.5

3) //round 8.111111 to 3 decimals
var result=Math.round(8.111111*1000)/1000  //returns 8.111
```

Comment: The OP want to make from 1724.1000000000001: 1724.11.

Answer (score 1):

you can try `toFixed` to fix to 2 decimals, below is the code.

```
var num=1724.1999;
alert(num.toFixed(2));​
```

result `1724.20`

Answer (score 0):

To round a number to 2 decimals:

```
var num = 1724.1000000000001;
num = Math.ceil(num*100)/100;

// num == 1724.11
```

Or, try this:

```
var num = 1724.1000000000001;
function round(num, decimals){
    var d = Math.pow(10,decimals)
    return Math.ceil(num*d)/d;
}

console.log(round(num,0))
console.log(round(num,1))
console.log(round(num,2))
console.log(round(num,3))
console.log(round(num,4))
// 1725
// 1724.2
// 1724.11
// 1724.101
// 1724.1001
```

Comment: The OP want to make from 1724.1000000000001: 1724.11.