# Roundup function javascript

Tags: javascript

In excel, we have a function:
    **ROUNDUP(number,num_digits)**

Is there same function in javascript?

Please help me.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191088/how-to-round-up-a-number-in-javascript

Comment: using a search engine gives the answer in 2 seconds, not worth opening a question in SO for...

Answer (score 7):

because  javascripts Math.ceil function doesnt support digits, you have to make your own.
like this:

```
function roundUp(number, digits)
{
    var factor = Math.pow(10,digits);
    return Math.ceil(number*factor) / factor
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `ceil()`

```
Math.ceil(0.7); // returns 1
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil for more info and how to do the decimal adjustment part.

Answer (score 0):

var num = 123.456
num.toFixed(1) //returns 123.5

Comment: toFixed rounds normally, it doesnt round up