# Need help to round up decimals Javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers, rounding

Im trying to round up 2 number and adding them after.

var a = 12.24;
var b = 12.27;

i want them to round up to 12.5 so when i add these 2 numbers the result will be 12.5 + 12.5 = 25

Comment: So, you want to round to the nearest 0.5?

Comment: You want to round the value to the nearest 0.5 irrespective of the decimal value? eg. 12.005, 12.1, 12.49 etc etc...

Comment: Voted to reopen: duplicate does not show how to round to nearest half.

Comment: "Bathsheba yes, i want to round to nearest 0,5

Comment: Why not add both numbers before rounding them? It will get a value of 25.

Comment: Will answer once re-opened, unless a better duplicate is found.

Comment: im new here so dont know how to reopen it, but i didnt think of the way that @ikeMiguel wrote, so now i added them first and then used math.round and it gaved me the right result, so Thanks guys :)

Comment: @Bathsheba: I've reopened it, but rounding to the nearest half is exactly like rounding to the nearest 10th, you just use a different multiplier/divisor.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Indeed but it's less obvious to the less mathematically inclined.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Indeed, that's why I undid my close vote and posted a CW. :-)

Comment: Can you kindly accept one of the below answers when applicable?

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as [shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5191133/157247), using a different multiplier/divisor. In that question, they wanted the nearest 10th; in this question, you want the nearest *half*. So instead of

```
var num = 12.24;
num = Math.ceil(num * 10) / 10;
alert(num); // 12.24
```

...we use

```
var num = 12.24;
num = Math.ceil(num * 2) / 2;
alert(num); // 12.5
```

Answer (score 1):

To round to the nearest half, use

`Math.round(a / 0.5) * 0.5;`

To round **up** to the nearest half, use

`Math.ceil(a / 0.5) * 0.5;`
But note two things:

1. Floating point arithmetic might still cause a fractionally-rounded number to be off. (But note that half-rounded numbers can be represented accurately in floating point to the 52nd power of 2).
2. You can achieve your result by summing the numbers then rounding the result. That will be more numerically stable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following. Here is a [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkb0zho7/).

```
var a = 12.24;
console.log(roundHalf(a)); // 12.5
var b = 12.27;
console.log(roundHalf(b)); // 12.5
var result = roundHalf(a) + roundHalf(b);
console.log(result); // 25

function roundHalf(num){
    return Math.ceil(num * 2) / 2;
}
```