# JavaScript round up without decimal

Tags: javascript

I have a code in JavaScript

```
shipingcostnumber * parseInt(tax) / 100 + shipingcostnumber
```

returns number as `6655.866558` so I cover it in parentheses like:

```
(shipingcostnumber * parseInt(tax) / 100 + shipingcostnumber)
```

now it returns like `73213.8` which is correct number.

> I need this number to be round up to `73214` and without any decimal.

So I made :

```
var nf = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  maximumFractionDigits:0, 
  minimumFractionDigits:0
});
```

and changed my code to:

```
nf.format(shipingcostnumber * parseInt(tax) / 100 + shipingcostnumber)
```

and it returns `73,214`. It did round up my number but also added `,` **how do I remove that decimal?**

Comment: I don't catch why wrapping the whole expression in parentheses changes the final result...

Comment: @Shidersz it's for tax percentage

Comment: I can understood the formula, but for me `shipingcostnumber * parseInt(tax) / 100 + shipingcostnumber` and this `(shipingcostnumber * parseInt(tax) / 100 + shipingcostnumber)` should give the same output, not differents ones...

Comment: @Shidersz well i don't know what to say i can't explain it unless share the output which i did, probably is math thing that works with parentheses :)

Comment: What do you expect for something like 73213.1?

Comment: @JonP no i expected `73214` (round up) and i have it now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round up a number in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191088/how-to-round-up-a-number-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to write your own function. Just use `Math.ceil(n)`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil