# How to round 0.023 to 0.03 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, rounding

How to round 0.023 to 0.03 in JavaScript

This is what i tried. but it gives 0.024
`var abc = 0.023, factor =  0.003;
abc = Math.round(abc / factor) * factor;
console.log(abc);`

how should i get 0.03

Comment: What is the logic behind that rounding? Do you want to round up to the next tenth?

Comment: Yes. I am calculating commisions from payments

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round to at most 2 decimal places (only if necessary)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary)

Comment: See the duplicate question and use `Math.ceil` instead of `Math.round`.

Comment: I think perhaps what you want is `Math.round(abc * (1 + (factor * 100)) * 100)/100`, but your question is very unclear.  You need to explain that you're doing two things: 1) Modifying the price by some commission factor (assumption: a percentage) and then rounding the resulting value to two decimal places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
abc = Math.ceil((abc/factor)*factor * 100) / 100;
```

ceil rounds up a number to the integer value.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean rounding float number up. I found solution here: [How to round up a number in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191088/how-to-round-up-a-number-in-javascript)

First parameter is number that you want to round. Second parameter is number (integer) of numbers after point that you want to get.

```js
function roundUp(num, precision) {
   precision = Math.pow(10, precision)
   return Math.ceil(num * precision) / precision
 }
  
 result = roundUp(0.023, 2)
 console.log(result)
```