# How to get the ceil value after 2 decimal places using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to achieve the following:

suppose `x = 321.31125`

Now I want the ceil value after the 2nd decimal point ... so the expected result should be `321.32`

Note: I know rounding which will return 321.31 but I want 321.32

Comment: Take a look at [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726630/formatting-a-number-with-exactly-two-decimals-in-javascript) where your question has been already answered and well explained. Simply use toFixed() method as  `(321.31125).toFixed(2)`.

Comment: @KateOrlova using `.toFixed()` does not round the number though, which was what the OP asked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just multiply by 100, take the ceiling of that new number (32131.125 => 32132), then divide that by 100.

```js
var x = 321.31125
console.log(Math.ceil(x * 100) / 100)
```

Edit: If you are looking to create a function, you could always do something like [this post details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5191133/5743929):

```js
function roundUp(num, precision) {
    precision = Math.pow(10, precision)
    return Math.ceil(num * precision) / precision
}

console.log(roundUp(321.31125, 2));
```

Comment: That I already did, but I was looking for method if exists which will ceil automatically upto the decimal point I want.

Comment: @Manik I added a function you could implement yourself to do this. To the best of my knowledge though, no functions are built in that would allow you to do this.

Comment: Thank you .. it really helps

Answer (score 2):

You must have to try this

```
Math.ceil(Math.round(-36.3 * 100)) / 100
```

in javascript there is 0.1+0.2 === 0.3 is **false

for -36.3 you have to round that calculation
so

```
    -36.3 * 100=-3629.9999999999995
```

so use for ceiling number

Comment: you can also use 
`       
let a = "-36.3".split(".");       
parseFloat(a[0] + "." + (a[1] ? (a[1][0] || "0") + (a[1][1] || "0") : "00"));      
     `

in javascript te calculation for 0.1+0.2 is            
(1/16+(1/10-1/16))+(2/16+(2/10-2/16))

Answer (score 0):

You could multiply by 100, ceil that value and divide by 100 again, ie

```
321.31125 * 100 = 32131.125
ceil 32131.125 = 32132.0
32132.0 / 100 = 321.32
```

Comment: That I already did, but I was looking for method if exists which will ceil automatically upto the decimal point I want